# How to make elasticsearch disregard spaces between certain queries?

Tags: elasticsearch, query-analyzer

My elasticsearch documents have a field `Name` with entries like:

```
Samsung Galaxy S3
Samsung Galaxy Ace Duos 3
Samsung Galaxy Duos 3
Samsung Galaxy S2
Samsung Galaxy S (I9000)
```

On querying this field with the following query **(notice the space between "s" and "3")**:

```
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "Name": {
        "query": "galaxy s 3",
        "fuzziness": 2,
        "prefix_length": 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It returns `"Samsung Galaxy Duos 3"` as a relevant result, and not `"Samsung Galaxy S3"`.

The pattern I notice for such a task is to disregard the space between any number and any single alphabetical character, and make the query. For example then, `"I-phone 5s"` should also be returned by `"I-phone 5 s"`.

Is there a nice way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to change your analyser to break up the string on a change from text to number - using a regular expression would help (this is based on the [camelcase analyser](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-pattern-analyzer.html#_camelcase_tokenizer)):

```
curl -XPUT 'localhost:9200/myindex/' -d '
     {
         "settings":{
             "analysis": {
                 "analyzer": {
                     "mynewanalyser":{
                         "type": "pattern",
                         "pattern":"([^\\p{L}\\d]+)|(?<=\\D)(?=\\d)|(?<=\\d)(?=\\D)"
                     }
                 }
             }
         }
     }'
```

testing the new analyser with your string:

```
-XGET 'localhost:9200/myindex/_analyze?analyzer=mynewanalyser&pretty' -d 'Samsung Galaxy S3'
{
  "tokens" : [ {
    "token" : "samsung",
    "start_offset" : 0,
    "end_offset" : 7,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 1
  }, {
    "token" : "galaxy",
    "start_offset" : 8,
    "end_offset" : 14,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 2
  }, {
    "token" : "s",
    "start_offset" : 15,
    "end_offset" : 16,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 3
  }, {
    "token" : "3",
    "start_offset" : 16,
    "end_offset" : 17,
    "type" : "word",
    "position" : 4
  } ]
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry I cannot upvote your answer because stackoverflow doesn't allow me. I believe this is a positive step towards what I'm trying to achieve. Is there a way I can tell elasticsearch to boost scores if a number and a text beside it is exactly matched (irrelevant if there is a space or not between them)? Thank you so much for the help!